# How to name the variable with the value of another variable? JS

Tags: javascript, string, redux

Is there a way to call a variable based on the value of another variable, which is not always the same?

**Example:**

```
var color = 'black';
var [color] = 'whatever'; // the variable name here would be 'black'
```

**Reason for usage:** In the reducer of Redux I receive an action that holds a particular value

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
const { size, color, object } = action;
switch (action.type) {
    case (DO_SOMETHING): {
    // instead of name 'output' below, I want to have a value of 'color' 
        let output = object;
        if (size) { 
            output = callExternalFunction(output, size);
        }
        return { ...state, [color]: output };
    }
```

**My goal:** If it is possible to do, I will be able to turn the return into this:

```
return { ...state, [color] };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an object to hold your variables names? For instance :

```
var color = 'black',
    variables = {};

variables[color] = 'whatever'; // { black : 'whatever' }

return { ...state, variables['black'] } // { ...state, 'whatever' }
```

Does that fit your needs? Maybe I misunderstood the question

Comment: The whole and only purpose of this struggle is merely to condense the size of the code by a few characters. And your solution does not achieve that.

Comment: Oh, so your code works, but you just wanted to make it shorter? I didn't get your point then.

Comment: I was not specific enough in the post :)

Comment: In the return statement how do you know variables['black'] the value name is "black".You have hardcoded it.

Comment: It should return variables[color]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` object for that. Try this:

```js
var color = 'black';
window[color] = 'whatever';
alert(black);
```

**Edit:**

As @Tavish Aggarwal mentioned this will make the variable global, if you really don't want that you could use `eval()` instead.

But [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269921/8621941), as the saying goes, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: Seems to work, but is it a reasonable and practical way of doing for the sake of mere condensation of the code?

Comment: @Eduard attaching variable to window is not a good practice. As it makes it a global variable.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal I see, probably should just leave the code in a way it is now. Thanks!

Comment: I thought about using `window`, but I wanted to avoid using a global variable. That's why I suggested using a local object instead of `window`.

Comment: Yes, but code suggested by you is not what @Eduard want.

Comment: @Eduard I upadated the code for another solution, however I don't think using globals is such a bad thing, as long as you "control" you code.