# Why when I eval() the responseText from an Ajax call does the word "undefined" appear?

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval

I have a simple test shown below.  It works fine, but for some reason the word "undefined" is appearing in the popup.  Nothing is leading me to understanding what is undefined.  Has anyone experienced this before?

**HTML**

```
<html><head>
<style>#popup{border:1px solid black;background:#eadcce;padding:10px;margin:35px;display:none;}</style>
<script>
function popup(){
    var z;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){z=new XMLHttpRequest();}else{z=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    z.onreadystatechange=function(){if(z.readyState==4&&z.status==200){
            if(z.responseText != ''){
                    document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML=eval(z.responseText);
                    document.getElementById('popup').style.display="block";
            }
    }}
    z.open("POST",'/test2.php');z.send();
}
</script></head><body>
Push the button to open the popup: <button onclick="parent.popup();">Open Popup</button>
<div id="popup"></div>
</body></html>
```

**test2.php**

```
console.log("test");
```

Everything works great except the word "undefined" appears in my popup.  Does anyone know why?  I'm using Firefox 55.0.3.

Comment: `eval` executes javascript code. I think you are looking for `JSON.parse`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does eval do and why its evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269797/what-does-eval-do-and-why-its-evil)

Comment: `var a = console.log('foo'); console.log('a ->', a);`

Comment: @KevinB i like using the shortcut:  `console.log({ a });`.

Comment: @KevinB, that doesn't solve my problem.  The word "undefined" still appears in my popup.

Comment: The code you are evaling evals to `undefined`. therefore `undefined` is being assigned to `document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML`, thus causing your modal to display the text `undefined`. it's doing exactly what you are instructing it to do. My code snippet confirms that by showing you that `console.log('foo')` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Amy, that is not part of my question.

Comment: @KevinB, ostensibly, simply evaluating `var a=console.log("test");` would remove the "undefined," but it didn't.

Comment: haha. no, you're missing the point.

Comment: `function foo() { doSomething();}` for example, when called, returns `undefined`. evaling `foo()` will result in `undefined` being returned.

Comment: @KevinB, that's why I'm asking the question.  I'm not understanding something.  The actual code from which this example was derived works perfectly... other than printing "undefined" as the first row of text.  It appears everything evaluates as "undefined."

Comment: Because what you're evaluating has no return value.  Not complicated.

Comment: Note that only you can see the duplicate banner, and i agree that it is an incorrect duplicate. not much we can do about it unless it ends up closed.

Comment: No, `eval` is not evil... if you read the question you'll see that there are several resources it links to talking about when eval is not evil. Are you seriously executing arbitrary code returned by a service? `eval` returns whatever the last statement in the string evaluates to. `eval('10')` returns `'10'`. `eval('var x = 10')` returns `undefined`.

Comment: that's unrelated to the question JDB.

Comment: Though, I would suggest not using eval in this case. it simply isn't needed, change the php to just return the string you want rather than console.log and then eval will not be necessary. You can still then use console.log to log it if you want directly within the javascript.

Comment: @KevinB, regrettably, this is only a test case to demonstrate the problem.  I actually do need to execute Javascript returned to the popup.  If there's a way to do it without using `eval()` or first saving the script to a file, I'm very interested to know what it is.

Comment: Ah, if your php is returning javascript, then yes your only options are appending a script tag, or eval. If appending a script tag, the method would need to change from POST to GET, and at that point it would simply replace the ajax request altogether.

Comment: @KevinB, I have no objection changing from POST to GET, where can I learn more about that solution?

Comment: Chill man... the duplicate question explains what `eval` does. That was the point. I have no opinion on whether or not `eval` is evil (it's quite handy in some scenarios, and I have no wish to make an argument to W3 that it be removed)... that said, you should know it has potentially severe consequences, which the linked question covers. And yes... eval executes arbitrary code, and you are getting that code *from a service*. That's quite dangerous, but if you know what you're doing then it's acceptable.

Comment: `var s = document.createElement('script'); s.src = '/test2.php'; codeThatAppendsToHeader(s);` for example. all you'd be doing is creating a script tag and appending it. however, you wouldn't be able to read it's contents to get the modal text, you'd have to obtain it some other way such as calling a function within the returned js

Comment: Setting the src of a script tag is a good idea, as @KevinB recommends. You may need to change the response type of your PHP page, though, as an incorrect MIME type (e.g. `text/html`) could cause some browsers to get confused.

Comment: The only difference between `eval`-ing network-supplied code versus inclusion via `<script>` tag is that `eval`'d code can get access to local variables. If you do `function foo() { var bar = 5; eval(something); }`, then the `eval`'d code can access (and change) the local var `bar` inside the `foo` closure. This may be desirable or undesirable, depending on your requirements.

Comment: @apsillers - That's not the only difference. `eval` tends to be much faster, but using a script tag makes debugging significantly easier. Also, [eval falls afoul of certain CSP rules](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSEval), which may or may not be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` evaluates JavaScript code and returns the result of the last statement evaluated. The function `console.log` returns `undefined`, so `eval('console.log("test")') also returns`undefined`(after printing the string`test` to the browser's log).

If you don't want your dialog to include `undefined`, don't make the last stement in your evaluated JavaScript string be a call to a function that returns `undefined`. For example, the string

```
console.log("test"); "foobar";
```

will return the string `foobar` when evaluated with `eval`, since that's the value of the last statement.

Similarly, the string

```
console.log("test"); ['a', 'b'].indexOf('a');
```

will return `0` when evaluated, because that's the returned value of the `indexOf` call in the final statement.