# Calling Typescript function with string in place of multiple arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript function, with multiple arguments, I would like to call with a single string. E.g.
`fn(a: string, b: number, c: boolean) {...}`

For example, suppose I have
`let str: string = "a: 'A', b: 5, c: false";`
Is there are a way (short of parsing this string) to call the function directly? Obviously just the call
`let result = fn(str)`
does not work.

Comment: You can use JSON format and stringify then `JSON.parse` the string. Probably use an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there are a way (short of parsing this string) to call the function directly?

**Short answer:**

Nope.

---

**Longer answer:**

Javascript does not provide a good way to encode function and argument lists as strings.

You need to encode that data somehow as a string, and then decode that data into the right format to use the data it contains.  You could encode it as JSON for instance:

```
const json = '{ "a": "A", "b": 5, "c": false }'
const { a, b, c } = JSON.parse(json)
fn(a, b, c)
```

But this means encoding/decoding that string according to your custom logic, which you said you don't want to do.

---

**Bad answer:**

Use eval:

```
const myEvilStr = "fn('A', 5, false)"
eval(myEvilStr)
```

This is interesting academically, but uh, yeah, don't do that. Ever.

Some reading on why not to do this, in case I haven't sold it:

[what does eval do and why its evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269797/what-does-eval-do-and-why-its-evil)

[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)